# What is the correct English name of these lines?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Hello.

I'm looking for the English name of these two lines in a two dimensional plane:

- they go through the origin
- they make angles of 45° and 135° with the $x$-axis, dividing the plane in two parts

From my native language, they would translate to "first bissector" and "second bissector" or "first diagonal" and "second diagonal", but I could not find any reference to such names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"The diagonal" (is $\{y=x\}$) and "the anti-diagonal" (is $\{y=-x\}$).

Comment: Actually, all lines other than vertical and horizontal lines are termed diagonal; see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal

Comment: @AkshajKadaveru, thx, yes, edited: the article "the" in front of the two I think distinguishes them.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this answer being flagged multiple times as "Low Quality"? There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @AhaanRungta, it is not glamorous or heroic enough for some, perhaps... :)  But I think it is accurate, given my experience. Conceivably non-native English speakers are not as attuned to the "the" as I am.

Comment: @paulgarrett Yeah, I think your answer is accurate, concise, and answers the question better than Akshaj or I do, to be frank. Once my vote lock is off, I'll upvote your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

These are lines where, if $\theta$ is the angle made with the positive $x$-axis, we have $ |\tan x| = 1 $. Thus, these are lines with **slope** $\pm1$.

Comment: yes, but I'd like to known if these lines have a specific name.

Comment: This is how I would state them. You could also say, if you don't want to state them algebraically, that they bisect the quadrants. But, other than that, I see no other way to state them.

Comment: So, in other words, if you want to attach a fancy name to them, you can say *quadrant bisectors*, but that's usually not as clear as just taking my suggestion and stating very explicitly what they actually are.

Answer (score 3):

If there was a specific English name, it isn't well known.

Comment: Ha! Very true. I wish I could upvote this. I will after my votelock is off.