# What's the name of the two diagonals in a 2D plot?

Tags: coordinate-systems

In a 2D plot (with x and y), what's the correct name of the diagonal lines, i.e. the line at 45° and that at 135°?

Comment: I would call them something like "the two $45^\circ$ diagonals". Possibly "the lines $x=y$ and $x=-y$".

Comment: I would call them the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$. Together, they are the graph of the equation $x^2=y^2$

Comment: Related: [What is the correct English name of these lines?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584759)

Answer (score 0):

$y=x $ and $y=-x $ are the equations of the diagonals in Cartesian coordinates.