# What is a common word for horizontal and vertical lines/directions?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I would like to differentiate between vertical and horizontal lines/directions in a dot pattern from diagonal lines. However, I am lacking the vocabulary for it. For instance, here I would like to differentiate between the blue arrows and the black arrows. Is there any term/word for this?
[image]

Comment: Depends on the context and audience. I would be fine with "horizontal" and "vertical."

Comment: In the context of 2-dim. euclidean coordinate geometry, (if you treat the black as x-y axes and the blue as x'-y' axes) you could relate the coordinate systems by a linear mapping - a rotation - (which is a rigid transformation), which fixes the origin.

Comment: [axis-aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-aligned_object) lines and [cardinal directions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction)?

Comment: @William actually the audience is biologists mostly and some mathematicians.

Comment: @geocalc33 Can you elaborate on that? All I am looking for is a terminology for a text.

Comment: @achillehui I thought about that but I am not sure if cardinal directions include the black lines and the blue lines as well. But that's ok. I can use "diagonal" for blue ones. Axis-aligned seems to be the best suggestion so far.

Answer (score 1):

It is very customary to look at a picture such as yours, and to immediately establish two distinguished perpendicular directions. Perhaps not coincidentally, the most popular distinguished directions are the ones in your picture that are painted black.

Since you are interested in words, I point out that your black horizontal axis is traditionally known as the axis of abscissas. Your black vertical axis is traditionally known as the axis of ordinates.

You have drawn your blue directions as bisecting the Cartesian coordinate axes in black. But upon inspection of the definition of [diagonal](https://www.lexico.com/definition/diagonal), we find that any direction not one of the four black directions can legitimately be called diagonal. So, I propose that "diagonal direction" is one way to describe your blue directions.

Also worth considering is "[skewed](https://www.lexico.com/definition/skew) direction".

As an example, consider measure theory. It is standard to consider only rectangles "with sides parallel to the coordinate axes". A rectangle along your blue directions does not satisfy this requirement.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584759